# Is there any way to tell that the page has scrolled over a certain div?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am wondering if there is a way to tell if the page has scrolled over a certain div. I am trying to change the color of a div when it has past a certain point on the page. I know I can use the scrolltotop method to do the job:

```
if($(window).scrollTop() > 0){
//code
}
```

Although I am wondering if I would have to get the divs height on the page and then go from there or is there a built in method to check if a div has been scrolled to?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you can do is take the sum of the scrollTop and innerHeight and when it equals to the scrollHeight, you've reached the end of the div.something like this:

```
$('divselector').bind('scroll', function()                              {
                            if($(this).scrollTop() + $(this).innerHeight()>=$(this)[0].scrollHeight)
                            {
                              alert('End of div');
                            }
                          })
```

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/doktormolle/w7X9N/)**

Answer (score 1):

May be like this

Get the scroll height of div in variable `divHeight`

check if current `Window.ScrollTop > divHeight` is greater than this variable

apply the chnage